# watching controllers scope from angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am passing data from a controller, into a directive.  The controller is changing the data, however I can not get the directive to respond when the data in the controller changes.  Here is a link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcardleliam/ReJQq/1/.

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <h1 foo>Prop: {{prop}}</h1>
</div>

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.prop = 0;
  var f = function() {
      $scope.prop = $scope.prop += 1;
      $timeout(f, 1000);
  }
  f();

})
.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope) {
        console.log('initial prop', scope.prop);
        scope.$watch(scope.prop, function() {
           console.log("prop changed"); 
        });
      }
  };
});
```

The "console.log("prop changed");" should be called every time the controllers $scope.prop property changes, but it is not.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this in directive:

```
scope.$watch('prop', function() {
   console.log("prop changed"); 
});
```

Refer to the property as 'prop' instead of `scope.prop`.

Comment: Yea, I just figured it out as well.  Thanks.  Here's an updated JSfiddle, which has a few additional changes: http://jsfiddle.net/mcardleliam/ReJQq/2/

Comment: So that answers the question?

Comment: Yes, that answers the question.  My issue was that I was trying to call the property directly on scope (i.e. scope.prop). Instead, the first attribute to the $watch function needs to be a string (i.e. 'prop')